# Wordpress show number of posts within the serie and loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am not sure how to describe my request, which means that I have had a hard time Googling it. Anyway what I am looking for is the following:

Lets say I have a archive with 15 posts. The archive page is restricted to 10 posts per page. Now I would like to show on the first page `post 1-10` and on the second page `post 11-15`. I tried to google it but with no luck. All I did find was a general `wp_query` post count:

```
<?php
echo $wp_query->post_count;
?>
```

I guess it shouldn't be too hard to accomplish correct? Anyone who can help me out here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the thing that you wanted is so easy,
wordpress query do this default for you,
install wp-pagenavi plugin its show a pagination non the footer and only thing you need to do is set the post limits on 10 in wordpress general setting section.

if this is not what you wanted, so please explain with an example.

********** i found out what you mean of this ***********

first you have to get posts_per_page , you can get that value whit usin one of these codes

```
$default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

or

```
global $wp_query;
$total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
```

after that you need to know witch page your in , so you can use this code to get that

```
$current = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
```

now we need a simple calculate to make the numbers you needed,

```
<?php 

    $ppp = intval(get_option( 'posts_per_page' ));
    $current = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
    $last = $ppp * $current;

    echo 'post from : ' . ( ($last+1) - $ppp). ' to : '.$last;
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks; it doesnt seem to count the posts but just the pages right? I'd like a function that just counts (no navigation required) the posts and shows them on the page. So on page 1: post 1 - 10 and page 2: post 11 - 15. Thanks

Comment: let me say that you actually want to show number like (1-10) or (11-15) in your page , true?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for helping me out. 2 things go wrong. On page 1 i get: post -9 to 0. And on the last page i get post 10 to 20, but there only are 15 posts... Something seems to go wrong there? Thanks!

Comment: hi, your right, i dont have access to keyboard for typing but i know the solution, in a few hours i'll fix the answer as you want, but before that i'll be appreciated if toy vote up my answer.